# Locked out of RDP access to EC2 Instance - due to Windows firewall

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

While accessing the EC2 Instance over RDP, I have configured the Windows Firewall of the server to use its default configuration.
I got immediately locked out of this Instance and cannot access it with RDP ...

Any way to reconfigure the Windows firewall via the AWS Terminal?

Can I re-attach the EBS volume to a new Server that is not blocked for RDP?

Other ideas?

Comment: Hello, Very good tip! Took a while to set-up SSM (roles, etc) and then PowerShell to configure FW rules. But Worked.

Answer (score 5):

You can use AWS System Session Manager (SSM) to connect to Windows and Linux instances even when locked out. SSM does not even require a working network interface.

The first item is to to use SSM to update the SSM agent on the instance. Then you can remotely connect to your server. It is very cool and I make sure all my instances have an updated SSM agent installed.

[AWS System Session Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-session-manager/)

Comment: Got access back using SSM. I disabled Windows Firewall for testing, then went to turn back on. Windows said "Windows Defender Firewall is using settings that may make your device unsafe". I stupidly clicked "Restore settings" and lost RDP access.

Comment: Managed to make this same mistake trying to limit Windows Defender resource usage today. Set up the Manager as instructed, ran the "AWSSupport-TroubleshootRDP" Automation on FixAll mode, only then succeeded at using RDP again. Thanks.